# odoo never ending loop

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying create a module that converts AD date to BS date but i got a problem that while entering the AD date odoo keeps on loading for hour and hour. I think its searching in nepali_date, so its taking long time. How can i solve this? 
Thank u in advance.

```
 nepali_date=((2000, 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31),(2001, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
         (2002, 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),(2003, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),
         (2004, 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31),(2005, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
         (2006, 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),(2007, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),
         (2008, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 29, 31),(2009, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
         (2010, 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),(2011, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),
         (2012, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30),(2013, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
         (2014, 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),(2015, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),
         (2016, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30),(2017, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
         (2018, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),(2019, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31),
         (2020, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),(2021, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
         (2022, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30),(2023, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31),
         (2024, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),(2025, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
         (2026, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),(2027, 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31),
         (2028, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),(2029, 31, 31, 32, 31, 32, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
         (2030, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),(2031, 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31),
         (2032, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),(2033, 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
         (2034, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),(2035, 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 29, 31),
         (2036, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),(2037, 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
         (2038, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),(2039, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30),
         (2040, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),(2041, 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
         (2042, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),(2043, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30),
         (2044, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),(2045, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
         (2046, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),(2047, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
         (2048, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),(2049, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30),
         (2050, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31),(2051, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
         (2052, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),(2053, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30),
         (2054, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31),(2055, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
         (2056, 31, 31, 32, 31, 32, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),(2057, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),
         (2058, 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31),(2059, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
         (2060, 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),(2061, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),
         (2062, 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31),(2063, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
         (2064, 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),(2065, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),
         (2066, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 29, 31),(2067, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
         (2068, 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),(2069, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),
         (2070, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30),(2071, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
         (2072, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),(2073, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31),
         (2074, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),(2075, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
         (2076, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30),(2077, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31),
         (2078, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),(2079, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30),
         (2080, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30),(2081, 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30),
         (2082, 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30),(2083, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30),
         (2084, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30),(2085, 31, 32, 31, 32, 30, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30),
         (2086, 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30),(2087, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30),
         (2088, 30, 31, 32, 32, 30, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30),(2089, 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30),
         (2090, 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30))
start_english=datetime.date(1943,04,14)
end_english=datetime.date(2034,04,13)
start_nepali="2000/01/01"

class Date(models.Model):
_name = 'date'
english_date = fields.Char(required=True, string='English Date')
nep_date = fields.Char(compute='_converttonepali', store=True, string='Nepali Date')

@api.multi
@api.depends('english_date')
def _converttonepali(self):
    yearsd = 2000
    monthd = 1
    eng_date = input(self.english_date)
    engl_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(eng_date, '%Y/%m/%d')
    engli_date = datetime.date(int(engl_date[0:4]), int(engl_date[5:7]), int(engl_date[8:]))# .strftime("%Y, %m, %d")
    dayslapsed = (engli_date - start_english).days
    for item in nepali_date:
        for month in range(1, 13):
            if dayslapsed >= item[month]:
                monthd = month + 1
                yearsd = int(item[0])
                if monthd == 13:
                    monthd = 1
                    yearsd =yearsd + 1

    self.nep_date = str(yearsd) + '/' + str(monthd) + '/' + str(dayslapsed + 1)
    self.nep_date = datetime.date(int(self.nep_date[0:4]), int(self.nep_date[5:7]),int(self.nep_date[8:]))
    return self.nep_date
```

Comment: Indent your code properly, and include all import statements necessary to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that odoo is still waiting for a value at:

```
eng_date = input(self.english_date)
```

You need just to remove `input()`:

```
eng_date = self.english_date
```

Comment: Thank u for your suggestion but again i got the error

Comment: @UpasanaBasnet Update your question with the new error message.